# How can we construct radical axis of 2 circles where one is inside the other one?

Tags: geometry, euclidean-geometry, geometric-construction, power-of-the-point

How can we construct radical axis of 2 circles where one is inside the other one? For example in this case.

[image]

On this web site http://mathafou.free.fr/pbg/sol139.html they construct one but it's not explained.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Just draw a circle which cuts both. Then draw radical axsis and their intersection is radical center $R$. Then the line perpendicular to line across centers through $R$ is their radical line. [image]

Comment: Thank you @Aqua